Flutter desktop app doesn't launch from another process on Linux
I am trying to run a desktop flutter application on linux from another application. I can't get it to run.
I tried using posix_spawn and fork/exec.
waitpid returns error 126 in the status-argument.
But the flutter application starts if you start it manually.
Has anyone encountered this problem?
I tried using posix_spawn and fork/exec.
